# Writing to jsp outputStream giving illegal state exception

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I am using Jasper Reports, trying to print a jsp page with my report, so that a user can see the report on the browser itself. In my jsp I wrote a code like this:

```
String filename="report4.jasper";
    String reporttype="html";
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/projectmanage","***","***");
               System.out.println("Connection Established");
     String path = application.getRealPath("/");


     JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path + "/" + filename, null, conn);
     System.out.println("Report Created...");

    **OutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();**

     JRExporter exporter = null;

     if( "pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
     {
          response.setContentType("application/pdf");
          exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
     }
```

Line in bold is giving the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.ServletResponseWrapperInclude.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapperInclude.java:65)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.report1_jsp._jspService(report1_jsp.java:82)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout1_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f1(layout1_jsp.java:120)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout1_jsp._jspService(layout1_jsp.java:75)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using apache tiles in my project. I don't understand if tiles is using the outputStream of my report jsp already? Please help.

Comment: In your stack trace, there is the JSP engine kicking in (org.apache.jsp), most likely on a "layout1.jsp" file. That may be the layer where the response's stream is already accessed. If you're accessing java code from the JSP, well may be you shouldn't (use a direct servlet instead ?)

Comment: Like GPI said. You shouldn't put logic inside a JSP. The exception on the other hand is thrown because likely `getWriter()` was already called on the response. Therefor you must use `getWriter()` in other code or it will throw an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream()

Comment: @GPI, thanks for your valuable comments. According to your suggestions, I put my code inside my controller now. The report is printing fine now and there is no error on the browser, but eclipse is throwing the same error in the background, i.e, illegalStateExeption.

Comment: You should not use servlet output stream in exporter parameter of JRExporter. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer following code it should clear your picture.

```
JRExporter exporter = new JRExporter();
    ByteArrayOutputStream os=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, os);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE,Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS,Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);


    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + "one.xls");
    response.getOutputStream().write(os.toByteArray());
```

Note here `OUTPUT_STREAM` is used as buffer for exporter.
The above code is when I am exporting my document as xls file. You can do same for pdf file.

Hope this helps you.